# Whose Name in App Store?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I'm only 16 and I've recently signed up for the apple developer program (individual). However, I used my mom's credit card since I don't have my own. I was granted permission and all that (I have the account and I have been testing my apps on my iDevice). I've changed every piece of information afterwards to my real name (My apple ID had my real name prior to me buying the developer account.)

Now, my question is will my name appear in the appstore or will my mom's name appear in the appstore? I don't know which one because in my developer profile it says Apple ID: My name and some other info and then under Developer ID it says my moms name.

However, in iTunesconnect, There is no sign of my mothers name and it only shows my name for everything. Does this mean that it will show my name?

If it does show my mom's name, how can I change that?

Please and thank you in advance!
- J

Comment: Next time you might want to look into getting one of those prepaid cards and registering it in your name so you can use your own info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/5_SigningContractsandBanking/SigningContractsandBanking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH21-SW1

The account has a contract. The contract has an "entity name" - the name of your "company". That is the name that appears at the App Store. It does not have to be a human being's name; it could be something made up, like "Zampabalooie Enterprises". Me, I use my actual name.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just to clarify, so I have the page open visible in the first diagram of the link you sent me. I see the two contracts for paid apps and iAd and beside them in the "Legal entity" field it shows my name. Also, in the top right corner it shows my name and in the settings it shows my name. Does this mean it will show my name in the appstore? I haven't requested for iAd or anything, I just want to release free apps at the moment. Thank you again so much! Will give rep once I get 15 -_-

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure this means that your name is the company name that will appear at the App Store.